# Oracle query fast in sqldeveloper, slow in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle

I want to execute the following query and put it on a gridview in my asp.net app

```
select *
from INDICATORS, places, places_sales
where places_sales.id = places.id
and 
INDICATORS.line  in (select line from lines)
```

the lines table has like a 28000 records and INDICATORS like 18000

This query is executed in oracle sql developer in 6 seconds, but in my asp.net application (with oracle dataacess as connector) takes like 20 minutes

Is there a way to optimize my query?

Comment: Are you sure the query is that slow in asp.net, or are you rendering all the results to a browser window, which is what's taking most of that time?

Comment: @hmqcnoesy you're right, I debugged my code and what takes most the time is render the results into a gridview, even when my gridview is paginated :S how can I solve this?

Comment: as default pl sql developer doesnt fetch all results, that might be the reason

Comment: Implement paging on the query itself (probably in the WHERE clause) - that is, only grab a subset of data each time you fill the Gridview control. Right now, you're grabbing all the data, and even with Paging enabled in the Gridview, it still has to deal with all that data.

Comment: Disable painting in the control until you're done populating it, then re-enable painting.  Not sure if this is possible in your control, but in a spreadsheet control we used to use this solved a lot of performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do to speed it up.

Firstly, is there a join between places or places_sales to INDICATORS?

If there is, you shoul add it, you're probably getting a cartesian.

Now, for the optimization piece, try the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM indicators, places, places_sales
 WHERE places_sales.id = places.id
       AND EXISTS
               (SELECT ''
                  FROM lines l
                 WHERE l.line = indicators.line)
```

Comment: There's a good explination for the difference here: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:442029737684

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be for you to use the GridView with paging

Please see link to understand more on paging of GridView http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5aw1xfh3.aspx

A nice example can be found here http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=339

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to place and make an **index** to the table so that queries are more fluid.

uses the type **CLUSTERED**  [look this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

I really was something like a table of more than 60000 rows and the index sort it out